# Deploy Laravel in var/www/html

Tags: php, laravel, server, centos, htdocs

I have the following file structure on my server

/var/laravelapp -> this is the entire laravel project.

/var/www/html/eduapp - > this is the public_html folder which has a folder called eduapp with the public contents of laravelapp.

The login register and home page work
https://example.com/eduapp/

when i click on the other buttons in the homepage the url becomes https://example.com/routename therefore giving an error

if we manually add eduapp in the link eg. https://example.com/eduapp/routename it works!!

any suggestions or solutions?

Comment: You can set the environment variable `APP_URL` as `https://example.com/eduapp` in your `.env` and laravel will know to use that as the base url for generating routes

Comment: can you tell me what is current `APP_URL` in `.env` file?

Comment: @UdhavSarvaiya The default value for `APP_URL is http://localhost.` The default value for `APP_URL` is defined in your `app.php` file inside config folder.

Comment: OK so i changed the app url to https://localhost/eduapp now i have new problem. the route only works when we remove the slash from href='/route' so it works in href='route' now i have to remove all '/' from hrefs.

secondly the ajax url doesnt work, i have to modify it as such : e.g this is the route:
Route::post('/student/ajaxcreate', 'StudentsController@ajaxcreate');

i have to use url : ajaxcreate in ajax

any suggestions?

Comment: Kindly check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35634530/laravel-routes-not-found-after-nginx-isntall/45596033, it might help you.

Comment: so these are the things that made the app work

1. changed APP_URL to https://example.com/eduapp
2. changed back button hrefs to href='../routename'.
3. Created Symlinks for public/img and storage folders.
4. Removed Slash from href routes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so these are the things that made the app work

1. Changed APP_URL to example.com/eduapp.
2. Changed back button hrefs to href='../routename'.
3. Created Symlinks for public/img and storage folders.
4. Removed Slash from href routes.