# laravel web route return 404 (cant find controller)

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, post, httprequest

I have seen many issues in the internet with this problem im having but they are all ver broad and hard to pin point exactly whats wrong with it, as there can be many variables to it, so I decided to list everything I have tried and maybe someone could help me.

**URL trying to access**

- https://mysub.mySite.dev/dirs

**Controller**

Directory `app/Http/Controllers/DirManagements/GetDirs.php`

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\DirManagements;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class GetDirs extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {

    }
    public function getResult()
    {
        echo "hi";
    }
}
```

**Web route**

```
Route::get('dirs', 'DirManagements\GetDirs@getResult');
```

**PHP artisan route:list**

```
Domain  | Method   | URI                        | Name | Action                                                     | Middleware                                                                                     
|       |GET|HEAD  | dirs                       |      | App\Http\Controllers\DirManagements\GetDirs@getResult      | web
```

**Nginx Sites-available file**

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    root /my-dir-to-web;
    index index.php index.phtml index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name mysub.mySite.dev;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    }
 
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/something/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/something/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
```

**Solution**

I dont know why laravel didnt include this to their installation docs when setting laravel up. added this to my nginx config and it worked.

```
location / {
     try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}

# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on /var/run/php5-fpm.sock
location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri /index.php =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php7-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
}
```

Comment: in your route use `/` instead of `\``  to be like this `DirManagements/GetDirs@getResult`

Comment: @Joseph That isnt the problem just tried it now. I have used ```\``` for the root directory and it works fine ```Route::get('/', 'DirManagements\FindFiles@getJson');```

Comment: As a general precaution, you should specify your routes with singlequotes `'`, as backslashes can be escaped in double quotes.

Comment: Has this something to do with the subdomain you've setup, perhaps? The route doesn't specify any domains.

Comment: @Qirel I was thinking it could be the subdomain.

Comment: From what you're showing us here, you haven't setup the domain specification on the route for that subdomain. You've set it for the main domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

I dont know why laravel didnt include this to their installation docs when setting laravel up. added this to my nginx config and it worked.

```
location / {
 try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}

# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on /var/run/php5-fpm.sock
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri /index.php =404;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php7-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There can be multiple things that can cause this. Try each of the following and let me know if it works:

- Make sure you have restarted the Server after creating the route.
- Make sure you have run the following commands to don't get any sort of cache issues:

  ```
  php artisan config:clear  
  php artisan cache:clear  
  composer dump-autoload  
  php artisan view:clear  
  php artisan route:clear
  ```

Comment: I tried this just now https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35634530/laravel-routes-not-found-after-nginx-isntall

Also didnt work