# Laravel Docker - The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD

Tags: laravel, nginx, docker-compose

I have a codecanyon project, and it can be installed in shared hosting without any error. Works like charm. However I was trying to install the same using docker-compose. I am getting error as "The POST method is not supported"

People have suggested for laravel codefix for such error, however in my case code works in Sharedhosting.  I think some issue with the nginx config not the laravel code.

I am not expert, hoping someone can point me out where to dig.

Laravel error stack
[image]
Docker Console
[image]

https://flareapp.io/share/x7K9Y2Lm#F31

I have also attached related code

[image]
[image]
[image]

default.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name starhardware.com.my;
    root /var/www/app;
 
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";
 
    index index.php;
 
    charset utf-8;
 
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }
 
    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
 
    
 
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

nginx.conf

```
user  www-data;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well.. Initially I was only looking for error at Laravel side. I did more investigation related to nginx and came to this thread.

[Laravel routes not found after nginx install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35634530/laravel-routes-not-found-after-nginx-install)

I followed it and it worked. my revised default.conf as below:

```
server {
    listen 443;
    server_name starhardware.com.my;
    root /var/www/app;
 
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";
 
    index index.php;
 
    charset utf-8;
 
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }
 
    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
 
     
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}
```